# Upgrading Linux mint 17 32- bit to Linux mint 17 64-bit

Tags: linux-mint, 64bit, 32bit

I have just upgraded my processor to a 64-bit processor and I would like to update my Linux mint 17 to 64-bit. How to do it?

```
$ uname -a 
Linux kmcodes-home 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:31:42 UTC 2014 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: it's possible but you'll need to have very deep Linux knowledge and a lot of time. See [Upgrading what might be the world's oldest running Linux install](https://www.theregister.com/2022/07/25/ancient_linux_install_upgraded/). Reinstall the new OS is far simpler and faster

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know about Mint, but I don't think many distributions support that kind of upgrade. Technically it shouldn't be impossible, but there are some pitfalls that will leave you with an unusable system.

It's probably easier to do a new install.

Comment: +1 for this recommendation. I'll just add: it is indeed *possible*. I've done it. But it is really, really tricky.

Comment: @Celada really? How? Wouldn't that involve reinstalling every single package to change the binaries to 64bit? And, if so, isn't that completely equivalent to reinstalling?

Comment: @terdon it's not equivalent to reinstalling because you get to keep all your config, which is valuable if stuff has been creeping into `/etc` and `/var` for years and you cannot possibly remember where it all is, and because you don't actually even need to reboot as long as you are already running a 64-bit kernel. As for "how?", well, I could outline it as a separate answer if you're really interested (short short version: you will break a lot of packages on purpose, and everything revolves sharply around `dpkg`), but really it's here be dragons territory.

Comment: It's called [cross-grading](https://wiki.debian.org/CrossGrading), and while it's become easier over the years, it's still tricky...

Comment: I've done this too, but it is much simpler to just install over the top then it is to upgrade. Just  don't format when you install and you will get the best mix of easy and working.